# Installing BeEF Produces Error: ruby: no such file or directory -- dk.rb (loaderror)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, init

I am trying to install beef, but in order to do that I need ruby.So far I've downloaded ruby from their official site. Then I downloaded the SQLite dll and extracted it into the ruby bin folder. Then I downloaded DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe and extracted it into the C:/ folder. Instructions told me to then open command prompt and go to the `devkit` path, but when I downloaded the devkit it automatically renamed itself to mingw so I went to the mingw path. Finally I tried to run

`ruby dk.rb init`

I got the error:

`ruby: no such file or directory -- dk.rb (loaderror)`

I have done the gem update and I have the latest gems and latest ruby and all of that.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was a while back, but if anyone have troubles with this in the future:

It seems like you are trying to this in windows, and that is pretty much impossible.
The guide on their wiki doesn't work and Ruby does not play well with windows.
Even if you get it up and running it is buggy.
your best bet is to download Vmware player and virtualise Ubuntu, the installation works like a dream and it runs smooth.

Assuming you get ubuntu up and running (that is pretty straight forward) do teh following:

Start the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You are now up to date and it is time to install Ruby and a couple of the dependencies, type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install curl git ruby build-essential libsqlite3-ruby libsqlite3-dev libssl-dev
```

Then we install Ruby virutal machine - rvm, with the following command

```
sudo curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```

now we will need the Terminal to act as a login-shell. The top menu might be hidden, but will show on mouse-over, so select Edit -> Profile Preferences.
In the pop-up window, select the "Title and Command" tab and check the "Run command as a Login shell" box.

Close the window and run the following command

```
sudo echo [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

followed by:

```
rvm pkg install zlib --verify-downloads 1
```

Note that it says that we are required to reinstall all rubies, so lets do that:

```
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Followed by this:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
```

It might take a while depending on your CPU, so stay patient and enjoy the multicolored terminal.

When it is finished, we tell rvm to use ruby 1.9.3, with the following  (extremely logical) command

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Finally we install Bundler by typing:

```
gem install bundler
```

We are now done with installing Ruby and Dependencies.
It is time to download BeEF, do that by typing the following:

```
git clone git://github.com/beefproject/beef.git
```

When it is done, navigate to the beef folder by typing:

```
cd beef
```

then we use bundler that we installed earlier, to install the beef bundle:

```
bundle install
```

Thats it, you have now sucessfully installed BeEF, congratulations! (start with "Ruby beef")